# Backbone.js: How to prevent multiple downloads of a related model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

Yes I know there is a plugin called [Backbone-Relational](http://backbonerelational.org) but I have [a serious problem with its fetchRelated function](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/issues/317) which, in my opinion, renders it useless for me.

So I was wondering if there are any alternatives? Or do we even need plugins like Backbone-Relational at all? How would you handle following scenario with pure Backbone:

Let's say we have two Backbone models: `Company` and `Person`. A Company instance can have many Persons. So `company.get('employees')` will return an array of Person IDs. If I want to get details of related employees, I'll have to iterate over the array and `fetch()` each of the Persons from server. But what if those Person instances have been already downloaded? Is there a clean way to make sure that there is no redundancy?

May be we can maintain a Collection for each model and dump every instance we download into it. Then we can download an instance only when it is not present in the Collection. But I think it will make code look horrible.

So please share your experience guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, I would give my Company model a Persons attribute. But you seem to forget collections also have a [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) method (as well as many other methods you'd find pretty useful, as the get method).

Also, as a last thing, I'd like to quote Backbone's doc (regarding the fetch method of Collections):
"*Note that fetch should not be used to populate collections on page load — all models needed at load time should already be bootstrapped in to place. fetch is intended for lazily-loading models for interfaces that are not needed immediately: for example, documents with collections of notes that may be toggled open and closed.*"

Comment: How does Collection#fetch help prevent multiple downloads of same instance?

Comment: Sorry it seems I misunderstood a little bit. Is your collection changing that much? How is it changing? As an example, to avoid downloading the same model again and again with growing collection, I used to pass a parameter with the highest id when fetching data. Also, can a person be part of several collection?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get what you mean by collection changing? Does is it mean adding/removing persons into it? If that is the case, then yes, persons can be added/removed from it. Yes person can be part of several collections, and that is the case which makes it tricky I guess. Let's say we have a model City which can have many Persons. We have a City instance London which has Persons p1, p2, p3 and p4 (already fetched). We have a Company Virgin which has Persons p3, p4, p5 and p6. Now when we fetch persons for Company Virgin, it will re-fetch p3 and p4 (which were already fetched).

Comment: As I stated, you could still pass the ids of the persons already fetched as a GET parameter, but it could get pretty ugly. I'll put more thought into it.

Comment: @craftsman as the server has no idea what it has already sent (well, he could...),  you really have only 2 solutions. Either fetch the models individually, or use a GET parameter to send the list of ids of the models already fetched. I really can't think of anything else. (thought about volatile collections, but the server wouldnt know of them ~~)